# Django: How to add to an ArrayField?

Tags: python, django

I have some questions about the ArrayField mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField

1. How do you add to an ArrayField? It's clear you can treat it like a regular field and do things like

```
my_array_field = []
my_array_field.save()
```

But what's confusing is I'm seeing everyone mention `my_array_field.append("something")` in StackOverflow questions. This isn't mentioned in the documentation at all. Moreover, if an arrayfield is `.append()`ed to, does it still require .save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do we need to call `save()`?

Yes, we need to call the **`save()`** method to ***COMMIT*** the changes to Database. Unless calling the `save()` method, the value only persists in the *scope* of the variable, *as the python list*. So, calling the `save()` is a *must do* thing while updating the values.

> how to add values to array field?

You can treat it as a *normal python list* object, because Django converts the db array field to *native Python `list` object*

```
model_instance.my_array_field = [1,2,3]
model_instance.save()
model_instance.my_array_field += [4,5,6]
model_instance.save()
```

> This isn't mentioned in the documentation

Probably, they may be missed to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField)
recommends to add some default value, and make it callable, so just try in your models:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    my_array_field = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255), default=list)
```

So you'll be able to add items in it just like with regular list in python:

```
my_array_field.append("something")
my_array_field.append("another_something")
```

And even more - you can use all methods like pop, extend, index etc.